# solution to Check for NullPointerException or ArrayOutOfBound Exception Java

Tags: java

In the following code, How do i guard against ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or NullPointerException because at some point, comment line 2 is going to give me a null value for the last entry in mydates[] or dates[mod] is going to throw an ArrayOutOfBoundException if i do `mod > dates.lenght` in comment line 1

```
if(dates.length >= 10){  
    mydates = new String[11];
    int last = dates.length;
    int mod = 0;
    int add_mod = (int) Math.round((double)Math.round(last) /10); 

    for(int i =0; i < dates.length; i++){
        if(mod >= dates.length){ // line1
            break;
        }

        mydates[i] = DateFormatter.GraphDateToString(DateFormatter.convertToDate(
                        Long.parseLong(dates[mod])));  //line2

        mod += add_mod;
    }

} else {
    mydates = new String[dates.length];

    for(int i =0; i < dates.length; i++){
        mydates[i] = DateFormatter.GraphDateToString(DateFormatter.convertToDate(
                       Long.parseLong(dates[i])));
    }

}
```

the way i solved it was to iterate over the array again and check for null values while populating a new array from there. But i want to find if there is a better solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the **object is null**.

In your case,

```
    if(dates[mod] != null){
        // PERFORM SOME OPERATION
    }


 for(int i =0; i < dates.length; i++){

            if(mod < dates.length){ // line1
            // SOME OPERATION

            if(dates[mod] != null){
                mydates[i] = DateFormatter.GraphDateToString(DateFormatter.convertToDate(
                        Long.parseLong(dates[mod])));  //line2
            }
        }
 }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: From the OP: **the way i solved it was to** `iterate over the array again and` **check for null values** `while populating a new array from there.` **But i want to find if there is a better solution out there.**

Comment: The OP did iterate but did not include a null check in the code. So just recommended that. I would appreciate any improvisation. :)

Answer (score 1):

If `mydates` is only 11 long, and you know `dates` is *at least* that long, maybe iterate using `mydates.length` instead:

```
for(int i =0; i < mydates.length; i++){
...
```

Then you won't get an `ArrayOutOfBoundException` when `i >= mydates.length`.

You won't get an `ArrayOutOfBoundException` for `mod` because of your check:

```
if(mod >= dates.length) {
    break;
}
```

For the null check, add

```
if (dates[mod] != null) {
    mydates[i] = DateFormatter.GraphDateToString(DateFormatter.convertToDate(Long.parseLong(dates[mod])));
}
```

To avoid the NullPointerException